# BUG: sleeping function called from invalid context at mm/slub.c:1719

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have allocated a pointer like

```
int *ptr = kmalloc(sizeof(int), GFP_ATOMIC);
```

And this pointer is deallocated in a timer function which having 5 second timeout value.

```
if( NULL != ptr )                
{                 
  kfree(ptr);
  ptr = NULL;
}
```

Please advise me what is wrong here.. Thanking in advance.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. What problem are you having?

Comment: BUG: sleeping function called from invalid context at mm/slub.c:1719

Comment: I am trying to free the allocated memory (by GFP_ATOMIC) from a timer timeout function.. Can I use that?

Comment: I don't see any reason why you couldn't.

Comment: You can't call a function that can sleep from that context, the error states everything you need...

Comment: how can I solve it.. Any suggestion

Comment: how can I solve it.. Any suggestion

Answer (score 5):

`kfree()` must not be used in an atomic context, such as a timer function.

Move it to another context, such as a workqueue.

Comment: Thanks for replying.. I am new in Kernel coding.. Could you please give me an example of workqueue.. or any good link for that?

Comment: See, for example, chapter 7 of [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).